# Opscenter 5.0: error when adding cluster, cluster added anyway, no clusters shown

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I have a new Opscenter installation. After adding my "existing cluster" to opscenter, I get the following error dialog boxes:

`Error creating cluster: Cannot read property 'datasource' of undefined`

and then

`Error getting basic OpsCenter information: Timeout exceeded`

My cluster is a Ec2MultiRegionSnitch cluster, I gave an external IP address. The file /etc/opscenter/clusters/my_cluster.conf is created, and the following output is in /var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log, I don't understand why Opscenter is not showing my cluster:

`2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 []  INFO: Starting factory <opscenterd.ThriftService.NoReconnectCassandraClientFactory instance at 0x279bbd8>
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 []  INFO: Adding new cluster 'my_cluster': {u'jmx': {u'username': u'', u'password': '*****', u'port': u'7199'}, 'kerberos_client_principals': None, 'kerberos': None, u'agents': None, 'kerberos_hostnames': None, 'kerberos_services': None, u'cassandra': {u'username': u'', u'seed_hosts': u'54.x.y.z', u'api_port': u'9160', u'password': '*****'}}
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 []  INFO: Starting new cluster services for my_cluster
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Starting services for cluster my_cluster
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Loading event plugins
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Done loading event plugins
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 []  INFO: Metric caching enabled with 50 points and 1000 metrics cached
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 []  INFO: Starting PushService
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Starting CassandraCluster service
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: agent_config items: {'cassandra_log_location': '/var/log/cassandra/system.log', 'thrift_port': 9160, 'jmx_pass': '*****', 'thrift_ssl_truststore': None, 'rollups86400_ttl': -1, 'api_port': '61621', 'use_ssl': 0, 'rollups7200_ttl': 31536000, 'kerberos_debug': False, 'storage_keyspace': 'OpsCenter', 'thrift_user': '', 'provisioning': 0, 'metrics_ignored_column_families': '', 'metrics_ignored_keyspaces': 'system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter', 'jmx_user': '', 'cassandra_install_location': '', 'kerberos_use_keytab': True, 'rollups300_ttl': 2419200, 'thrift_pass': '*****', 'jmx_port': 7199, 'metrics_ignored_solr_cores': '', 'metrics_enabled': 1, 'kerberos_use_ticket_cache': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_type': 'JKS', 'rollups60_ttl': 604800, 'ec2_metadata_api_host': '169.254.169.254', 'kerberos_renew_tgt': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_password': '*****'}
2014-07-27 08:51:19+0000 []  INFO: Stopping factory <opscenterd.ThriftService.NoReconnectCassandraClientFactory instance at 0x279bbd8>
2014-07-27 08:51:21+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Enterprise functionality: False
2014-07-27 08:51:21+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Cluster Name: my_cluster
2014-07-27 08:51:21+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2MultiRegionSnitch
2014-07-27 08:51:21+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Recognizing new node 54.x.y.z ('1518911012250133')
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Node 54.x.y.z has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Recognizing new node 50.x.y.z ('-5708006418797709')
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Node 50.x.y.z has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Recognizing new node 55.x.y.z ('1514538487336164')
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Node 55.x.y.z has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Version: {'search': None, 'jobtracker': None, 'tasktracker': None, 'spark': {u'master': None, u'version': None, u'worker': None}, 'dse': None, 'cassandra': u'2.0.9'}
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Node 50.x.y.z changed its mode to normal
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Adding Thrift connections to 50.x.y.z
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Node 54.x.y.z changed its mode to normal
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Node 55.x.y.z changed its mode to normal
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Adding Thrift connections to 55.x.y.z
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Using 50.x.y.z as the RPC address for node 50.x.y.z
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Using 55.x.y.z as the RPC address for node 55.x.y.z
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Using 54.x.y.z as the RPC address for node 54.x.y.z
2014-07-27 08:51:22+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Keyspaces: {'system_traces': CassandraKeyspace(name=system_traces, column_families=[], tables=[u'events', u'sessions'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '2'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'}), 'system': CassandraKeyspace(name=system, column_families=['IndexInfo', 'NodeIdInfo', 'schema_keyspaces', 'hints'], tables=[u'peers', u'range_xfers', u'schema_keyspaces', u'schema_columns', u'IndexInfo', u'schema_triggers', u'sstable_activity', u'peer_events', u'paxos', u'batchlog', u'NodeIdInfo', u'compaction_history', u'compactions_in_progress', u'schema_columnfamilies', u'local', u'hints'], attributes={'strategy_options': {}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}), 'OpsCenter': CassandraKeyspace(name=OpsCenter, column_families=['events_timeline', 'settings', 'rollups60', 'rollups86400', 'bestpractice_results', 'pdps', 'rollups7200', 'events', 'rollups300'], tables=[u'events_timeline', u'settings', u'rollups60', u'rollups86400', u'bestpractice_results', u'pdps', u'rollups7200', u'events', u'rollups300'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '2'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'})}
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Persisting agent configuration to Cassandra
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Initializing event storage.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Attempting to load all persisted alert rules
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  WARN: Ignoring scheduled job with type=best-practice, which is only supported with DataStax Enterprise.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Done loading persisted scheduled job descriptions
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 []  INFO: Starting to update agents' configuration
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Done initializing event storage.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Done loading persisted alert rules
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 []  INFO: Finished starting new cluster services for my_cluster
2014-07-27 08:51:27+0000 [my_cluster]  INFO: Stopping repair service`

Comment: Downgraded agents and opscenterd to 4.1.4 and the cluster has been added successfully, this is probably an issue with 5.0.0 with existing clusters (I'm running on Amazon Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer on the OpsCenter product.  This does appear to be a bug, and we're investigating it (OPSC-3252 is the internal ticket number, for your records).  On digging through the source code for this particular path, it looks like it may be an issue with permissions.  Try adding a cluster as an admin user or disabling authentication and see if that will work for you.

Comment: Ran, we may need some further information from you to completely resolve this.  Could you contact me at mikemac [at] datastax [dot] com so we can expedite the issue?  Thanks!